# MathJax: How do I write matrices on the same line?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

In answering [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160574/what-relative-masses-are-required-for-them-to-collide-n-times-in-this-scenario/160641#160641) question, I needed to multiply three matrices - which obviously involves writing them on the same line. I tried a couple of things, none of which worked, so my question is - how do you write collinear matrices?

Comment: More on LaTeX: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/136/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/804/2451 , http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11127 , http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68388 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works the same way you did it earlier in the answer, when you had a matrix and vector: just write the markup for the matrices one after another.

```
$$\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}$$
```

They don't all have to be on the same line, but as with any other MathJax expression, you can't have a blank line between the starting and ending `$$`s.

I went ahead and fixed the markup in the answer for you, as an example.